# sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root? for normal users

Tags: centos, sudo, cpanel

strangely I cannot run the sudo command for every new account I create that is not root. The server is completely new and wasn't touched so I don't know what's wrong.

for every command I try to run with sudo with a normal user I get

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

I tried various solutions I found on the web including

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

and

```
chown -R root:root /usr/bin
```

but nothing helped.

```
ls -l `which sudo`
```

shows

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 123832 Oct 15 02:14 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

and finally

```
type -a sudo | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs ls -lF
```

gives

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 123832 Oct 15 02:14 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: Was that `ls -Fl which sudo` or do you actually have a file called `/usr/bin/sudo*`? Also, is that really a . in the last position of the permissions string (`-rwsr-xr-x.`)? Finally, please edit your question and add the output of `type -a sudo | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs ls -lF`. Just to be on the safe side.

Comment: the file is called sudo, the * is added by putty and yes, there's a dot. I'll now add the result of your command

Comment: Oh, please also clarify that you're using putty. I doubt that will make a difference but the more information we have, the likelier someone can find an answer. OK, the `.` is indicative of a [SELinux issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102625/22222). Is this a machine you administrate? If so, please edit and explain your SELinux setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason new users automatically used `jailshell` which caused this incident. Switching to `bash` fixed the issue.